# Apply template function depending on runtime parameter

Tags: c++

Is there a way to instance the function depending on runtime parameters?

Something like this:

```
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <exception> 
    
    using namespace std;
    
    enum class EType{
        INT,
        DOUBLE,
        STRING
    }
    
    template<typename T>
    void print (const T& val){
        cout << val << endl;
    }
    
    template<typename T>
    void sum (const T& l, const T& r){
        cout << l + r;
    }


    template typename<T> load_parameter (const string& path, const string& name){
       const T arg = // read this parameter
       cout << arg;
    }
    
    template<typename F<typename P>, typename... Args>
    void apply_type_template_func(const EType e_type, F* function, Args... args){
        switch (type){
            case EType::INT:
                *F<int>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            case EType::DOUBLE:
                *F<double>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            case EType::STRING:
                *F<string>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            default:
            throw runtime_error("Unsupported Param Type");
        }
    }

int main()
{
    auto e_type  = EType::INT;
    apply_type_template_func(e_type, print);
    e_type  = EType::DOUBLE;
    apply_type_template_func(e_type, sum, 0.1, 0.2);
}
```

And can I make it somehow without using type deduction? For example, consider function that load parameter from yaml by it's name?

Comment: The example is weird. You can deduce `T` for `sum` and `print` from the arguments, but for some reason you want to make it dependent on the value of `e_type` instead? What is supposed to happen if you call `apply_type_template_func(e_type, sum, 0.1, 0.2);` with `e_type == EType::STRING`?

Comment: Good point, maybe exception. I wanted to simplify an example, but consider if there is a fucntion, that reads the parameter from a file by its name. In this case, you can not deduce the type.

Comment: Without a clearer example it is a bit hard for me to figure out how to answer, but you are probably implementing some form of `std::variant` and `std::visit` here. Maybe using them directly would be easier.

Comment: "instance the function depending on runtime parameters" isn't that the definition of function overload?

Comment: Some sample input / output would make this clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax `template<typename F<typename P>>` is wrong.

Moreover, you cannot pass template function (I mean `print` and set `T` afterward).

But you can for class:

```
template <typename T>
struct printer
{
    void operator()(const T& val) const
    {
        cout << val << endl;
    }
}

template <template <typename> class C>
void apply_type_template_func()
{
    C<int>{}(42);
    C<float>{}(4.2f);
    C<std::string>{}("Hello world");
}
```

That is why a way to pass template function is to wrap them in class or lambda:

```
auto lambda = [](const auto& arg){ print(arg); };
```

Note: Here, class (lambda) is not template, but its `operator()` is.

And indeed, to transform a runtime value into compile time value/type,
you have to dispatch at runtime (so with limited set of values) to compile time value.

As with `switch`:

```
template <template <typename> class C>
void apply_type_template_func(EType type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case EType::INT: C<int>{}(42); break;
        case EType::Double: C<double>{}(4.2); break;
        case EType::STRING: C<std::string>{}("Hello world"); break;
    }
}
```

Note that each branch should be valid, even if branch is not taken, so your variant with forwarding argument would be wrong, as all of `C<int>{}(arg)`, `C<double>{}(arg)`, `C<std::string>{}(arg)` should be valid (which is not the case for regular argument).